# How to write negative binary number?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So `0b1` is `1`. How to write `-1` in binary format?

The docs says that the leftmost bit is reserved for sign, but where is that leftmost bit? Even `0b11111111111111111111111111111111` is still a positive number. I naively tried `1b` with no success of course.

Comment: Just put a negative sign in front of the number. `-0b11111111111111111111111111111111`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```js
let a = -0b1;

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Simple as that, omg. I thought that I have to write the sign as a leftmost bit...